# Tapping push notification actions in iOS, without opening the app

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Tapping an incoming push notification by default opens or brings the app to the foreground. Overriding this default functionality doesn't make much sense. Except in the situation when the incoming message is an alert, that the user could "snooze" or postpone.

In my case, I added an action to my push notification. When long-pressing or swiping-down the notification, I give a "snooze 15 min" option, triggering a new local notification reminding the user of the previous alert. My app is written in React Native, using Expo SDK 49.

I'd like the app to remain in the background when the user taps "Snooze 15 Min", or open normally when tapping the notification itself above it. Is it possible, using react native /expo ? Or otherwise ?

I did not find any way to achive the expected result, and I guess it is not possible. Someone suggested adding "invokeApp": "false" which should avoid opening the app, but I need to avoid opening the app only when tapping the "snooze" option.

Many thanks in advance !

Lorenzo Sandini

https://cgmsim.com

[image]